# Visual Studio Build Avoidance when building many C# projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with a lot of C# projects. The dependencies are not cyclic and when I build a high level DLL it appears to be rebuilding all the project referenced DLLs that it is linked to before running the program.

This seems to be unneccessary because I did not change the code in those DLLs and they are at a lower level so the changes I made in the top level DLL should in no way effect the low level DLLs.

**How can I tell visual studio to only build DLLs that depend up the hierarchy chain not both ways.**

Comment: How are you triggering the build?

Comment: The Green run button. Do doing a Build [project name] from the Build menu.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Tools->Customize`

A dialog will open. Go to `Commands` tab. In `menu bar`radio select `Build | Project only`. Assign a shortcut to it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

When visual studio checks dependencies, it runs the build process. This is not necessarily building your project. In Visual Studio, if you navigate to *Tools->Options...->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run* you will see a drop downs labeled *MSBuild project build output verbosity*. If you change this to Detailed. When you build, you will see, in the output window, that it is verifying whether or not files have changed in order to determine if it should rebuild the project. This is why it appears to be building every time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following setting:
"Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" under Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / Build and Run.

Comment: That doesn't quite work because the main executable doesn't have hard project links to changed DLLs. I need something that basically says. Only compile DLLs if their code changed and upward dependencies IE DLLs that depend on the changed ones. The current behavior is recompiling DLLs that are unchanged that the changed DLL depends on.